# SQL Lite Trigger Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to execute the following query

```
String CREATE_TRIGGER_DELETE_PATIENT =
                 "CREATE TRIGGER " + KEY_USERID
                   +" BEFORE DELETE ON " +  TABLE_USERS
                   +" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN "
                   +" DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_RECORDS 
                   +" WHERE " + KEY_USERID 
                   + " = " + KEY_RECORDID +" END;";
```

However , there is an error (1) near "END": syntax error .

I reference the code with the tutorial on http://android-pro.blogspot.sg/2010/10/using-sqlite-database-with-android.html. I am unable to spot the mistake.

Can any one suggest a remedy?

Comment: How about you give us the generated SQL statement? This would help to sove your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving a `;` before `END` statement.

```
String CREATE_TRIGGER_DELETE_PATIENT =
                 "CREATE TRIGGER " + KEY_USERID
                   +" BEFORE DELETE ON " +  TABLE_USERS
                   +" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN "
                   +" DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_RECORDS 
                   +" WHERE " + KEY_USERID 
                   + " = " + KEY_RECORDID +"; END;";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you may check this http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html link it would be helpful to you.